# Vee-validate - Triggering field level validation only when $validator.validateAll() is called but not when the input field is touched

Tags: validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I have a scenario where a custom field validation rule to be triggered only when the submit button is clicked for that form and it should be triggered by calling $validator.validateAll() function itself. I don't want this rule to be triggered when I start making changes to the input field.

I have looked into .disable directive but looks it it will disable all the validation rules for that field which I don't want. I want to disable a specific validation rule and enable it later on the button click.

I am using vee-validate version 2.xx.

Answer (score 0):

try dynamic validation in vee validate.

[Dynamic Rules](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/dynamic-rules.html)